# Android Studio - How to Find and Change System Variables

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am currently trying to find out the values of $HOME and $ANDROID_AVD_HOME as I am having difficulties running an emulator.

I have searched through various posts to try and find an answer, people simply suggest "changing this variable", however I have no inkling how to find the value or location of these variables.

I would, ideally, like to know how to display their values then, if I need to, change them.

Comment: Usually, when you see things like written as `$NAME`, they refer to environment variables. Environment variables themselves have nothing to do with programming. For example, the `$PATH` environment variable refers to a list of directories in which the OS will attempt to find programs to run, if something tries running a program by its bare name, instead of providing a full path to the program. Instructions for changing environment variables varies by your development machine OS (Windows, OS X, Linux) and scope of the variable (per-user, system-wide).

Comment: I'm currently on Windows. Where would I be able to find and/or configure these environment variables?

Comment: Well, if you use Google to search on `change environment variables in windows`, you come up with lots of hits. In general, environment variables are accessible via the Control Panel, though the specific details may vary by Windows version. I do not use Windows much, and so my specific experience here is dated.